# Changing/setting a protected property in another class - PHP

Tags: php

Server PHP version is 5.3.0

I'm working with a series of tutorials in David Powers' book, PHP Solutions, Third Edition. They deal with file uploading (in this case, images) and thumbnail creation as images are uploaded.

This requires the use of three classes:

`Upload.php` - This handles file uploads

`Thumbnail.php` - This creates image thumbnails

`ThumbnailUpload.php` - This extends `Upload.php` and requires `Thumbnail.php`. It works with the other two classes to create thumbnail images as the main images are uploaded. It also adds the option to keep or delete the original image after the thumbnail is created and the option to add a suffix to the generated thumbnail's filename (neither of these features I am using now, but I may use them in other applications later).

As shown in the code below, `ThumbnailUpload.php` extends `Upload.php` and also requires the `Thumbnail.php` class. Since `ThumbnailUpload.php` is what's called in the `upload_page.php` page, it seems that `Thumbnail.php` is out of the loop, because my efforts to change the `$maxSize` protected property within it fail. After enough testing, it is clear that `Thumbnail.php` is not getting the new value.

I have read about Reflection and maybe this is the way to allow me access to the `$maxSize` property in `Thumbnail.php`, but the documentation doesn't make enough sense to a novice such as myself.

I want to be able to get a new value for `$maxSize` passed to `Thumbnail.php` and simply have no idea how.

**RELEVANT CODE: upload_page.php**

```
// max file size for images
$max = 1048576;

// max long side dimension in pixels
$maxSize = 150;

// upload pics and create thumbnails
require_once('ClassFiles/Image/ThumbnailUpload.php');
$loader = new ThumbnailUpload('../images/projects/project_1/');
$loader->setThumbDestination('../images/projects/project_1/gallery_1/thumbnails/');
$loader->setMaxSize($max); // see note 1 below
$loader->setThumbSize($maxSize); // see note 2 below
$loader->upload();
$errors = $loader->getMessages();
$names = $loader->getFilenames();
```

Note 1:
This sets the protected property '$max' in Upload.php so that the max file size in bytes can be changed as needed

Note 2: 
This is for changing the protected property '$maxSize' in Thumbnail.php except this throws a php error saying that this public function is undefined in ThumbnailUpload.php because it's actually in Thumbnail.php. So I added the public function to ThumbnailUpload.php and the error goes away but $maxSize in Thumbnail.php remains unchanged

**RELEVANT CODE: ThumbnailUpload.php**

```
namespace ClassFiles\Image;

use ClassFiles\File\Upload;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../File/Upload.php';
require_once 'Thumbnail.php';

class ThumbnailUpload extends Upload {

protected $thumbDestination;
protected $deleteOriginal;
protected $suffix = '_thb?'; // omit special characters to switch this on

public function setThumbSize($thumbSize) {
    if (is_numeric($thumbSize) && $thumbSize > 0) {
        $this->maxSize = (int) $thumbSize;
    }
}
```

**RELEVANT CODE: Thumbnail.php**

```
namespace ClassFiles\Image;

class Thumbnail {
protected $original;
protected $originalwidth;
protected $originalheight;
protected $basename;
protected $thumbwidth;
protected $thumbheight;
protected $maxSize = 100; // max long-side dimension in pixels
protected $canProcess = false;
protected $imageType;
protected $destination;
protected $suffix = '_thb?'; // omit special characters to switch this on
protected $messages = array();

public function setThumbSize($thumbSize) {
    if (is_numeric($thumbSize) && $thumbSize > 0) {
        $this->maxSize = (int) $thumbSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some people like to downvote when it is too wordy. It's probably better to edit your question with actual relevant code.

Comment: @Mikey It took a while to pare it down to this much. And the code isn't the question, it's the inability to access one class file with a setter method when the same procedure works being able to access another class.

Comment: Quite honestly, start reading your question from the top as if for the first time. It's nearly incomprehensible. Don't keep adding updates, and most certainly don't add them in the chronologically reverse order. Keep the question readable for anyone as a coherent question. Rewrite as necessary. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476.

Comment: @deceze Rewritten. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I get your problem right...

```
<?php

class Thumbnail {

    protected $maxSize = 100;

    public function setMaxSize($size) {
        $this->maxSize = $size;
    }
}

class Upload {

}

class ThumbnailUpload extends Upload {

    protected $thumbnail;

    public function __construct(Thumbnail $thumbnail) {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    }

    public function upload() {
        // not possible, as maxSize is only accessible from Thumbnail an
        // all of it's child classes
        $this->thumbnail->maxSize = 200;

        // that works, as setMaxSize is public
        $this->thumbnail->setMaxSize(200);
    }
}
```

If `setMaxSize` is also protected, than you can't change it from `ThumbnailUpload`. In this case, the class author don't want, that anyone can change this value. If you are the author, you might change the visibility of `setMaxSize` or add an new constructor parameter to Thumbnail

```
class Thumbnail {

    public function __construct($maxSize = 100)
    {
        $this->maxSize = $maxSize
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. ThumbnailUpload.php extends Upload.php I can't get the protected property `$maxSize` in Thumbnail.php to change. However I can change the protected property `$max` in Upload.php just fine. It's as though Thumbnail is inaccessible to any attempt to change `$maxSize`.